# MCMC Standard error

Tags: standard-deviation, python, standard-error, markov-chain-montecarlo

I need to make a simulation to calculate the integral of a pdf $f(x|D)$ over a region $T$.That is, I need to evaluate
$$\int_T f(x|D)\; dx$$

to do this, I just defined the function $g(x)=1$ if $x \in T$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x$ is not in $T$. So the integral that I want to evaluate is
$$\int_{D(f)} g(x)f(x|D)\;dx$$

where $D(f)$ is the domain of $f$, right? The Monte Carlo estimative of my integral is given by
$$\bar{I}=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N g(x_i), x_i \sim f$$

right? And the Monte Carlo Standard Error is 
$$SE= \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(g(x_i)-\bar{I})^2}$$

I made a Python function to calculate this:

```
def MCSE(g, estimativa):

#Size of the vector g (which is composed of 0 and 1)
N = int(len(g))
#Auxiliar vector vet
vet = []
for i in range(N):
    vet.append(float((g[i]-estimativa)**2))
#Calculate the standard error and return
SE = sqrt(np.mean(vet))
return SE
```

Is my function correct? Because when I estimate the integral and it gives a value close to the real value of the integral (which I know from other ways), it is giving values close to 0.5, which doesn't seems correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Monte Carlo estimate for $\bar I$ doesn't sum up any $x_i$, but you said that you're getting quite close? Perhaps you need to edit your question? As it is now your $\bar I$ is just the ratio of $T$ in $D(f)$

Comment: *Weigted by the 'importance' of $f$.